# Newer jQuery version causes a wrong AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using this js function to comunicate a web with an Arduino server:

```
function requestAction(actionId) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',  
        //contentType:  'text/javascript',  
          url: "http://192.168.2.102/requestAction",
          data: { "actionId" : actionId  },
          success:function(json) {
            jsonpRefPR(json);
          },
          processData: false,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonp: "callback",
          jsonpCallback: "jsonpRefPR",

      error:function() {
        alert("An error ocurred while requestAction()!");
      }
    });
}
```

with the jQuery v1.4.2 works like a charm and I have the following Request url:

```
http://192.168.2.102/requestAction?callback=jsonpRefPR&actionId=0
```

which is just what the Arduino expects, so everething works.

**BUT when I use the newer jQuery v1.9.1, I got the following wrong Request url:**

```
http://192.168.2.102/requestAction?callback=jsonpRefPR&[object%20Object]&_=1378730663347
```

so the Arduino doesn't "underestand" this URL and I got an error in the AJAX function...

What's wrong?!

Comment: remove `processData: false`

Comment: jQuery's up to 1.10.2 now, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `processData` parameter - you do not need it and it is preventing the `data` being serialised correctly.

Comment: I did and I still got error, but this time the Request url looks like:

[link]http://192.168.2.102/requestAction?callback=jsonpRefPR&actionId=0&_=1378741541529

the _=1378741541529 shouldn't be there, as shouldn't execute the error handler...

Comment: I added:

cache: true,

and I got rod of the  _=1378741541529 (wich is a time stamp) BUT it still launch the error handler, why?!?!